# Prometheus histogram metric inaccurate

Tags: nginx, logstash, httpresponse, prometheus

We have Nginx logs getting processed by Logstash into ES. And we can populate the response time graphs from that data. But we can retain logs only for a limited amount of time. Hence, Prometheus.
Using the logstash-output-prometheus plugin, I'm sending the `request_time` value as a histogram metric.

```
        prometheus {
          timer => {
            http_request_duration_seconds => {
              description => "HTTP request_time from Nginx logs"
              value => "%{[request_time]}"
              type => "histogram"
              buckets => [ 0.005, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 04, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 60, 120, 300, 600 ]
              labels => {
                api => "%{api}"
                method => "%{method}"
                status => "%{status_agg}"
                path => "%{uri_name}"
                host => "%{host}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

When I compared the 95th percentile values from Logstash vs Prometheus, they were very different at times.

For example,
[image: Comparison between Prometheus and Logstash graphs]

In the image above, the bottom graph is populated from Logstash ES. The values are around 10ms for 2 hosts and around 11ms for rest of the 4 hosts.

(ES query: `type:"nginx" AND host:"prod-lb" AND  uri_name:"/api/status" AND method:"GET" AND status:"200"`)

Prometheus shows value for 2 hosts to be around 10ms(✅) but rest 4 hosts are shown at around 18ms!

(Prometheus query : `histogram_quantile(0.95, sum by(le, path, host, method, status) (rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/api/status", host=~".*lb.*"}[2m])))` )

(Note that the buckets around these values are, 5ms, 10ms, 25ms)

Is this huge deviation expected?

How can I make this more accurate ?

Any other ways to retain more accurate response times ?

Comment: About more accurate response times with Prometheus, why don't you first add some buckets around 10ms (and maybe remove the buckets > 10s ?). Prometheus histogram knows your 95th percentile is somewhere between 10 and 25ms, but performs a linear interpolation to give you un single number . (cf: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#errors-of-quantile-estimation). Add more buckets around your estimation, you'll get more accurate results.